# How can I create a pop up button in front of Android's incoming and outgoing calls

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

Created a hat head or pop up icon/button which shall appear in front of the Android incoming and outgoing calls. I did it through service (broadcastreceiver), and not through activity.

Finally, I am running the app and calling and nothing is happening. 
While I am calling the service does not start, however the log shows that the method has been called .
What I am doing wrong? Why it is not working?

the receiver:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.i("LOG", "CallReciever onRecieve()");
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.v("LOG", "state is:"+state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            String num = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.v("LOG", "phone ringing, num:"+num);

                Log.v("LOG", "adding floating button");
                addAppButtonToCallScreen(context);//add out application to the main call screen

        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))//call ended or hanged up
        {
            //remove our button from screen
            removeAppButtonFromCallScreen();
        }
    }
/**
     * add our application to the main call screen
     * @param context 
     */
    private void addAppButtonToCallScreen(Context context) 
    {
        Log.i("LOG","addAppButtonToCallScreen()");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FloatingButtonService.class);  
        context.startService(intent);  
    }
```

the service:

```
public class FloatingButtonService extends Service  
{
    private WindowManager _windowManager;  
    private ImageView _floatingButton;
    private boolean _isMove;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {  
        Log.i("LOG", "FloatingButtonService.OnCreate()");
        super.onCreate();  
        _floatingButton = new ImageView(this);  //the logo bubble as imageView  
        _floatingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_call);   
        _windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE); 

        //set the layout params 
        final LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(  
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,  
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,  
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 

        myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;  
        myParams.x=0;  
        myParams.y=100; 


        // add a floatingButton icon in window  
        Log.v("LOG", "adding the view");
        _windowManager.addView(_floatingButton, myParams);  

        try{  
            //for moving the picture on touch and slide  
            _floatingButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
                WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsT = myParams;  
                private int initialX;  
                private int initialY;  
                private float initialTouchX;  
                private float initialTouchY;  
                private long touchStartTime = 0;  

                @Override  
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {  
                    Log.i("LOG", "floating button touch event");
                    //remove button bubble on long press  
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-touchStartTime>ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() && initialTouchX== event.getX())
                    {  
                        _windowManager.removeView(_floatingButton);  
                        stopSelf();  
                        return false;  
                    }  

                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                        touchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
                        initialX = myParams.x;  
                        initialY = myParams.y;  
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();  
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();  
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (_isMove==false)
                        {
                            startApp();//start our application
                        }
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
                        myParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);  
                        myParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);  
                        _windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, myParams);
                        _isMove=true;
                        break;
                    }  

                    return false;  
                }

            });  
        } catch (Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

    /**
     * show toast    */
    private void startApp() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pressed button weeeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

log:

```
01-08 18:03:56.745: I/LOG(10149): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:03:56.745: V/LOG(10149): state is:RINGING
01-08 18:03:56.745: V/LOG(10149): phone ringing, num:0549968089
01-08 18:03:56.745: V/LOG(10149): adding floating button
01-08 18:03:56.745: I/LOG(10149): addAppButtonToCallScreen()
01-08 18:04:04.645: I/LOG(10149): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:04:04.645: V/LOG(10149): state is:IDLE
01-08 18:11:45.765: I/LOG(10543): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:11:45.765: V/LOG(10543): state is:RINGING
01-08 18:11:45.765: V/LOG(10543): phone ringing, num:0549968089
01-08 18:11:45.765: V/LOG(10543): adding floating button
01-08 18:11:45.765: I/LOG(10543): addAppButtonToCallScreen()
01-08 18:11:57.950: I/LOG(10543): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:11:57.950: V/LOG(10543): state is:OFFHOOK
01-08 18:12:11.275: I/LOG(10543): CallReciever onRecieve()
01-08 18:12:11.275: V/LOG(10543): state is:IDLE
```

Comment: We can't tell you why code you haven't posted isn't working.

Comment: @GabeSechan Sorry, it is my mistake.